# How to make single line TextView scroll horizontally only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a little TextView with a single line. When the line is full of text, I want this TextView start scrolling horizontally not vertically.

To make a picture of this, it's like in the Apple's mail app when you fill the "To :" field.

I've tried different way but no one worked :/

```
CGSize size = textView.contentSize;
size.height = CGRectGetHeight(textView.frame);
size.width = 300;
textView.contentSize = size;
textView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate, cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a [`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) which behaves exactly like you described.